# How to do proper Error handling in RESTful web services?

Tags: java, web-services, rest, spring-mvc, error-handling

I am designing a restful WS API using spring-mvc.

If suppose a particular error (let's say: `MyCustomException`) occurs while server is executing code, and I want to return the `error_code` and `error_desc` detailing cause of the error to the client who is calling my WS, then what is the best approach to design this API in a generic way?

P.S.: Please note that if server does not encounter any error then this same API should return response object back to the client.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

For error handling, it is best to use heavily established standards. error_code and error_desc in the JSON response is not a heavily established standard, so I highly recommend against putting error information in the JSON/XML payload. Not following a standard increases the chance of error, misunderstanding, and often makes your development process longer.

Instead, I recommend using HTTP Status codes, and if you HAVE to provide more detailed information about an error, do it in the header.

See a explanation/list of the status codes here: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html

For example, if your server/service hits an unknown error, simply put a 500 status code (stands for Internal Server Error). If the user/client is not allowed to use that resource, use a 403 Forbidden. If the client sends a malformed request, send back a 401.

Spring has some very nice tools that make this process easier. For handling exceptions ACROSS your controllers, check out @ExceptionHandler and @ControllerAdvice.